# Screening for duplicates in a tuple - Python

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I am trying to create a function, `non_duplicates()`, that screens for duplicates for a given tuple `x`, and returns `False` if there is a duplicate, or returns `True` if there isn't any.

I am doing this by a `for` loop nested within another to iterate over the items twice to compare all the items with each other. I added a conditional that checks if the two items are equal, while their indices are not.

The problem is that the code is giving an equal `index` for different items for some reason, where I made sure that the index is linked with the iteration.

The answer for `non_duplicates(((0,0),(0,0)))` is the same as `non_duplicates(((0,0),(5,5)))`, both are giving `True` while it should not for the former.

When I checked `((0,0),(0,0))`, the indices are `"0,0    0,0    0,0    0,0"`, while for `((0,0),(5,5))`, the indices are `"0,0    0,1    1,0    1,1"`.

That is why the condition are not being met.

```py
def non_duplicates(x):
    y = 0
    for i, j in x:
        x1 = (i,j)
        for k, l in x:
            x2 = (k,l)
            if (x1 == x2 and x.index(x1) != x.index(x2)):
                y = y + 1
    y = y/len(x)
    if y == 0:
        answer = True
    if y > 0:
        answer = False
    return answer
```

Comment: Why do you unpack ``x`` only to repack it immediately? I.e. why do you use ``for i, j in x: x2 = i, j`` instead of ``for x2 in x:``? Why do you use ``x.index`` - are you aware that ``x1 == x2`` *requires* that ``x.index(x1) == x.index(x2)``? Are you aware of ``enumerate``? Why do you count *all* duplicates, instead of returning ``False`` on the first duplicate found?

Comment: i did use before this "for x1 in x:" and "for x2 in x:". It was giving the same answer as well. I am counting all duplicates because later on i will try to find them all and delete them in bigger tuples of 2-tuples. And no I am not aware that x1 == x2 requires that their indices are the same. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that uses the same logic as @Matt Shin's answer but also works for a tuple of tuples like your example show's you checking.

```
def non_duplicates(x):
    sorted_tuples = []
    for item in x:
        # sort every tuple in a tuple of tuples and returns a list of sorted tuples
        sorted_tuples.append(tuple(sorted(item)))

    # checks for duplicates using set
    return len(set(sorted_tuples)) == len(sorted_tuples)

print(non_duplicates(((0,0),(0,0))))

print(non_duplicates(((0,0),(5,5))))
```

Or if your tuple of tuples is really large and you care deeply about computation time. You could check after every element you add.

```
def non_duplicates(x):
    sorted_tuples = set()
    for count, item in enumerate(x, 1):
        sorted_tuples.add(tuple(sorted(item)))
        if len(sorted_tuples) != count:
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can try:

```py
def non_duplicates(x):
    return len(set(x)) == len(x)
```

Comment: This does not check for duplicates.

Comment: A set is a list of non-duplicated values. Your question also asks for a function that checks for duplicates in a Tuple, however your example shows you checking a tuple of tuples.

Comment: @newbie_in_python If len of set is the same as the len of the tuple, then there is no duplication in the tuple.

Comment: Sorry, that does answer my question. Thanks!